# Guidelines for Gesture Recognition using Kinect, OpenNI,NITE

Tags: kinect, gesture

I know this has been all over the net. I browsed a lot and found a lot of information about Gesture recognition .However i got more confused after reading most of them seem to work on Kinect Official SDK , Microsoft's SDK and i don't want to use them.

I need to develop it for Linux and was wondering if OpenNI, NITE gives me the flexibility to recognize a gesture.

I am trying to develop a sign language program, which recognizes the gestures and draws stuff(spheres,cubes etc) on screen,

Could any one give me a clear guidelines to begin this project.I have no clue where to begin it from.

Any help is welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: By "no clue where to begin" do you mean developing for the Kinect, or recognizing gestures using that system?

Comment: I meant for gesture recognition. Is there any specific algorithm i need to follow?

Comment: No, there is no specific algorithm to follow.  Recognizing gestures is done by using the skeleton data to watch what one or more joints are doing.  Check answers below for some links on good information.

Comment: I have written a short article on gesture recognition that explains the basics and principles behind gesture detection. It references both Evil Closet Monkey's article and Kinect Toolbox. https://presentationaid.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Recognition&referringTitle=Documentation It explains how for more complex gestures a machine learning method should be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For getting starting with understanding gestures I suggest checking out a blog post I made a while back:
http://www.exceptontuesdays.com/gestures-with-microsoft-kinect-for-windows-sdk-v1-5/

This, plus the post it links to, go into what makes up a "gesture" and how to implement them using Kinect for Windows SDK.

You can also check out thine Kinect Toolbox, which also does gestures for the official Kinect SDK:
http://kinecttoolbox.codeplex.com

These will give you a good understanding of how to deal with gestures.  You can then move those concepts and ideas into an OpenNI environment.

Answer (score 1):

If in your sign language system you want to use hand gestures you can have a look at [Kinect 3D handtracking](http://cvrlcode.ics.forth.gr/handtracking/). If it includes whole body movement then have a look at [KineticSpace](https://code.google.com/p/kineticspace/). Both tools work for linux but the first tool requires CUDA enabled GPU as well.

Answer (score 0):

- I think the Gesture recognition is not depended on whether you use Kinect Official SDK or OpenNI, if you can get the skeleton data or depeth image from the Kinect,then you can extract the gesture or postion from the relations between skeltons with times. As far as i know ,those SDKs are all provide those informations.
- I developed kinect on windows ,but the priciple are the same, I still suggest to know the principle about the Gesture recognition, then you can find the way to do recognition using other SDKs.